Странная ошибка в WinSock C++
Решил написать простой клиент-серверный чат без GUI на C++ (основные библиотеки WinSock2 + thread + future) Изначальный код был взят откуда-то с Github и тщательно изучен. Я решил добавить в него асинхронности, и после исправления всех ошибок, появилась странная ошибка с повреждением переменной хранящей IP адрес. Судя по выводу, на клиенте появляется ошибка WinSock2 #10061, а на сервере ошибка #10022. Также появляется исключение "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'SERVER_IP' was corrupted" и аналогичное только вместо 'SERVER_IP' 'IP_SERV'. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться! Код прилагаю.
Server:
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#include <future>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{

    //Key constants
    char IP_SERV[] = "";    // Enter local Server IP address
    cout << "Enter your IP: ";
    cin >> IP_SERV;
    cout << endl;
    int PORT_NUM = 0;   // Enter Open working server port
    cout << "Enter server port: ";
    cin >> PORT_NUM;
    const short BUFF_SIZE = 1024;           // Maximum size of buffer for exchange info between server and client

    // Key variables for all program
    int erStat;                             // Keeps socket errors status

    //IP in string format to numeric format for socket functions. Data is in "ip_to_num"
    in_addr ip_to_num;
    erStat = inet_pton(AF_INET, IP_SERV, &ip_to_num);

    if (erStat <= 0) {
        cout << "Error in IP translation to special numeric format" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    // WinSock initialization
    WSADATA wsData;

    erStat = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsData);

    if (erStat != 0) {
        cout << "Error WinSock version initializaion #";
        cout << WSAGetLastError();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "WinSock initialization is OK" << endl;

    // Server socket initialization
    SOCKET ServSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (ServSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Error initialization socket # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ServSock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "Server socket initialization is OK" << endl;

    // Server socket binding
    sockaddr_in servInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&servInfo, sizeof(servInfo));    // Initializing servInfo structure

    servInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servInfo.sin_addr = ip_to_num;
    servInfo.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUM);

    //erStat = 
    bind(ServSock, (sockaddr*)&servInfo, sizeof(servInfo));

    /*if (erStat != 0) {
        cout << "Error Socket binding to server info. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ServSock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else*/
        cout << "Binding socket to Server info is OK" << endl;

    //Starting to listen to any Clients
    erStat = listen(ServSock, SOMAXCONN);

    if (erStat != 0) {
        cout << "Can't start to listen to. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ServSock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Listening..." << endl;
    }

    //Client socket creation and acception in case of connection
    sockaddr_in clientInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&clientInfo, sizeof(clientInfo));    // Initializing clientInfo structure

    int clientInfo_size = sizeof(clientInfo);

    SOCKET ClientConn = accept(ServSock, (sockaddr*)&clientInfo, &clientInfo_size);

    if (ClientConn == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Client detected, but can't connect to a client. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ServSock);
        closesocket(ClientConn);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Connection to a client established successfully" << endl;
        char clientIP[22];

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientInfo.sin_addr, clientIP, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);    // Convert connected client's IP to standard string format

        cout << "Client connected with IP address " << clientIP << endl;

    }

    //Exchange text data between Server and Client. Disconnection if a client send "xxx"

    //vector <char> servBuff(BUFF_SIZE), clientBuff(BUFF_SIZE);                         // Creation of buffers for sending and receiving data
    char servBuff[BUFF_SIZE] = "";
    char clientBuff[BUFF_SIZE] = "";
    short packet_size = 0;                                              // The size of sending / receiving packet in bytes

    while (true) {
        auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [ClientConn, servBuff] {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = recv(ClientConn, (char*)servBuff, 1024, 0);                  // Receiving packet from client. Program is waiting (system pause) until receive
            cout << "Client's message: " << (char*)servBuff << endl;
        });


        auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [clientBuff, ClientConn, ServSock] {
            int temp2 = 0;
            cout << "Your (host) message: ";
            fgets((char*)clientBuff, 1024, stdin);

            // Check whether server would like to stop chatting 
            if (clientBuff[0] == 'x' && clientBuff[1] == 'x' && clientBuff[2] == 'x') {
                shutdown(ClientConn, SD_BOTH);
                closesocket(ServSock);
                closesocket(ClientConn);
                WSACleanup();
                return 0;
            }

            temp2 = send(ClientConn, (char*)clientBuff, 1024, 0);

            if (temp2 == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                cout << "Can't send message to Client. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                closesocket(ServSock);
                closesocket(ClientConn);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
        });
    }

    closesocket(ServSock);
    closesocket(ClientConn);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;

}

Client:

#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <inaddr.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#include <future>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
    //Key constants
    char SERVER_IP[] = "";      // Enter IPv4 address of Server
    cout << "Enter server IP, what you need to connect: ";
    cin >> SERVER_IP;
    short SERVER_PORT_NUM = 0;              // Enter Listening port on Server side
    cout << "Enter server port: ";
    cin >> SERVER_PORT_NUM;
    const short BUFF_SIZE = 1024;                   // Maximum size of buffer for exchange info between server and client

    // Key variables for all program
    int erStat;                                     // For checking errors in sockets functions

    //IP in string format to numeric format for socket functions. Data is in "ip_to_num"
    in_addr ip_to_num;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP, &ip_to_num);


    // WinSock initialization
    WSADATA wsData;
    erStat = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsData);

    if (erStat != 0) {
        cout << "Error WinSock version initializaion #";
        cout << WSAGetLastError();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "WinSock initialization is OK" << endl;

    // Socket initialization
    SOCKET ClientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (ClientSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Error initialization socket # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ClientSock);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else
        cout << "Client socket initialization is OK" << endl;

    // Establishing a connection to Server
    sockaddr_in servInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&servInfo, sizeof(servInfo));

    servInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servInfo.sin_addr = ip_to_num;
    servInfo.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT_NUM);

    erStat = connect(ClientSock, (sockaddr*)&servInfo, sizeof(servInfo));

    if (erStat != 0) {
        cout << "Connection to Server is FAILED. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(ClientSock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "Connection established SUCCESSFULLY. Ready to send a message to Server" << endl;


    //Exchange text data between Server and Client. Disconnection if a Client send "xxx"

    //vector <char> servBuff(BUFF_SIZE), clientBuff(BUFF_SIZE); // Buffers for sending and receiving data
    char servBuff[BUFF_SIZE] = "";
    char clientBuff[BUFF_SIZE] = "";

    short packet_size = 0;                                              // The size of sending / receiving packet in bytes

    while (true) {
        
        auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [packet_size, clientBuff, ClientSock] {
            int temp1 = 0;
            cout << "Your (Client) message to Server: ";
            fgets((char*)clientBuff, 1024, stdin);
            
            // Check whether client like to stop chatting 
            if (clientBuff[0] == 'x' && clientBuff[1] == 'x' && clientBuff[2] == 'x') {
                shutdown(ClientSock, SD_BOTH);
                closesocket(ClientSock);
                WSACleanup();
                return 0;
            }

            temp1 = send(ClientSock, (char*)clientBuff, 1024, 0);

            if (temp1 == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                cout << "Can't send message to Server. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                closesocket(ClientSock);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
        }});
        

        auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [packet_size, ClientSock, servBuff] {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = recv(ClientSock, (char*)servBuff, 1024, 0);

            if (temp == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                cout << "Can't receive message from Server. Error # " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                closesocket(ClientSock);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            else
                cout << "Server message: " << (char*)servBuff << endl;
        });

    }

    closesocket(ClientSock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

P.S Извиняюсь за большой пост.
P.P.S Просьба писать только решения или советы по решению проблемы.

Вы вообще отдаете себе отчет в том, что в char IP_SERV[] = ""; вы выделяете аж один байт? Куда вы после этого что-то пишете в cin >> IP_SERV;, если там места - только на нулевой завершающий символ?!! Говорить о чем-то дальше бессмысленно, пока вы не исправите ошибку выхода за границы памяти — прямое неопределенное поведение...
